# Subraction of two fields is not performing good

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is the script I used to add two field values.

```
$('.price').keyup(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.price').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('#subt').val(sum);
});
```

This script adds both fields and displays (-) minus before value.

```
<input type="text" name="total_quantity" class="subt" id="subt" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" class="subt"/>                              

$('.price').keyup(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.subt').each(function() {
        sum -= Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('#tot').val(sum);
});

<input type="text" name="balance_quantity" class="tot" id="tot" value=""/>
```

If total_quantity field value = 10000
& quantity field value = 5000

then result should be 5000 but it display as -15000

[Result for subtraction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uS3l.jpg)

Comment: You are finding sum and expecting difference ? `sum += Number($(this).val());`

Comment: Well... `0 - 10000 - 5000 = 15000`

Comment: sum -= Number($(this).val());

Comment: How to subtract then?

Comment: If you start at zero and are always subtracting positive values the result will always be negative. What you are doing is simple math ... work it out what you need to do on a piece of paper first then modify code accordingly

Comment: When calculating it takes as 5000-10000 = -5000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do in your script is to substract from 0 all the value of your .price input. So of course 0 - 10,000 - 5,000 = 0.

You can do this, change initialization of substraction then don't substract total_quantity field, you can do this by changing the class name:

```
<input type="text" name="total_quantity" class="init_subt" id="subt" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $quantity; ?>" class="subt"/>                              

$('.price').keyup(function () {
      var sum = $(".init_subt").val();
      $('.subt').each(function() {
        sum -= Number($(this).val());
      });
      $('#tot').val(sum);
 });
```

Comment: Works good but displays minus before number.                                              Ex: 10000 - 5000 = -5000

Comment: only 2 first one is total_quantity and second one is quantity

Comment: Thanks Buddy works great. I have given init_subt as class name for total_quantity so when subtracting it takes as 5000-10000 = -5000. I have assigned that class name for quantity so now it works great.